# translating class_name to active record migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Document, and a User model. The document model can have an owner, which is from the user Model. How exactly would one map the following to a migration? Source or reference on this would be ***greatly*** appreciated.

**Document Model**

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
end
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :documents do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :owner #how do I set class name here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just give `owner_id` and migrate.

Comment: @Pavan, Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You can't use `t.references :owner` while your `class_name` is `User`.If you want `owner_id` as `foreign_key`,you have to just give `t.integer :owner_id`.

Comment: Also,there is no option as `class_name` in migrations i guess

Comment: You don't need to specify the class name in the migration. `t.references :owner` should do the trick to create the field you need in the database.

Comment: Have you actually tried running the migration?  Do you get an error?  Your migration as it stands should generate an `owner_id` column in the `documents` table (plus an index).  The fact that the owner is actually in a table called `users` is irrelevant to the `documents` table.  Your `belongs_to` statement in the `Document` class will correctly sort that out.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**how do I set class name here?**

You dont have to. That line is just to create a column. You set the class name in your Model, which you have already done